# AlphabetIndexer with Custom Adapter

Tags: android, adapter

Can someone show me an example of how to use `AlphabetIndexer` with a Custom Adapter that uses a `getView`?  I have it working with a standard adapter, but have no clue how to implement it with a custom adapter.

Thanks

Comment: I am doing something similiar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224233/alphabetindexer-with-custom-adapter-managed-by-loadermanager

Comment: Here I created a sample application in Android ,Which is similar as Iphone Alphabatical Indexer http://mukeshyadav4u.blogspot.in/2012/06/alphabatical-indexer-in-android.html

Answer (score 8):

If you're using a LoaderManager to manage your adapter's cursor, you'll want to make a small adjustment and override your adapters swapCursor method:

```
public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor c) {
    // Create our indexer
    if (c != null) {
        mIndexer = new AlphabetIndexer(c, c.getColumnIndex(Books.TITLE),
                " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
     }
     return super.swapCursor(c);
 }
```

Everything else remains just as @vsm describes.

Comment: Actualy i want to implement the AlphabetIndexer and the Fast Scroll as per the Alphabetic search as like Contact List in Android. So how to do it ??

Comment: I have tried the demo which display the list of data with the Indexer like a,b,c,d.... etc... But now want to implement the Fast Scroll based on the click of the Side panel which display the Text as A,B,C,D. . .  etc

Comment: @PratikButani if you're not using `LoaderManager` follow the example posted by @vsm.

Comment: I want ot use Indexer for Spinner.? how can i?

Comment: @PratikButani that's a broad question not suitable for comments. I suggest you submit your own question to stackoverflow.

Comment: Can't we do something like this rather than creating new AlphabetIndexer everytime


@Override
 public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
  mAlphabetIndexer.setCursor(newCursor);
  return super.swapCursor(newCursor);
 }

Answer (score 7):

Hi this is how I use AlphaIndexer

```
private final class ContactListItemAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter
        implements SectionIndexer {
    AlphabetIndexer alphaIndexer;

    public ContactListItemAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
        super(context, layout, c);
        alphaIndexer = new AlphabetIndexer(c, NAME_COLUMN_INDEX,
                " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    }   

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            .... 
            a normal getView
            ....
    }  

    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        return alphaIndexer.getPositionForSection(section);
    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return alphaIndexer.getSectionForPosition(position);
    }

    public Object[] getSections() {
        return alphaIndexer.getSections();
    }
}
```

NAME_COLUMN_INDEX is the index of the column in database schema.

...

If this is not what you need, please add some code about which should be the class to extend and so on.

Anyway I hope this helps.

Comment: hello, i wanna ask: what could i do if i don't get my item from database