# Insert TextView at Certain Spots in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I have a List View that Displays songs in alphebetical order being populated by this method

```
public void updatelist(){

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,null);
    int j =0;

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{

            int ALBUM_ID =  cursor.getInt((cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ID)));

            int pathcolumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

            String path1 = cursor.getString(pathcolumn);

            String album_url = null;

            Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, ALBUM_ID);

            album_url = uri.toString();
            ContentResolver res = this.getContentResolver();
                // Album
                String album_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM));

                String year = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.YEAR));
               // String year = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.NUMBER_OF_SONGS));


                // artist
                String artist_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.ArtistColumns.ARTIST));
                // display name
                String DisplayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));

                //title
                String Title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE));

                songtitle.add(Title);
                Collections.sort(songtitle);
                artistname.add(songtitle.indexOf(Title), artist_name);
                albumname.add(songtitle.indexOf(Title), album_name);
                path.add(songtitle.indexOf(Title),path1);
                albumartwork.add(songtitle.indexOf(Title),album_url);
                j++;
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }
              Collections.sort(songtitle);

              adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.song,songtitle);

                setListAdapter(adapter);


        }
```

My Question is i want to insert Dividers whenever the first letter of the SongName Changes. 
I have this method to get the first letter of the songname if it is different than the previous..

```
   private void alphebetdividers(ArrayList<String> songtitle2) {
    String newString = null;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<Character> letters = new ArrayList<Character>();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while( j < songtitle.size()-1){
            if(songtitle2.get(i).charAt(0) == songtitle2.get(i+1).charAt(0)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), songtitle2.get(i).charAt(0) + "== " + songtitle2.get(i+1).charAt(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                // Display Char with TextView
                String songName = songtitle2.get(i);
               newString = songName.substring(0, 1);


            }
      j++;
      i++;

}
```

How would i display this in the list view at the appropriate spots. Thank you and i will give u a good rating if u know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an Adapter that implements `SectionIndexer`, specifically [`AlphabetIndexer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AlphabetIndexer.html). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033059/android-cursoradapter-with-alphabetindexer) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115920/alphabetindexer-with-custom-adapter).

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using an Adapter... there are libraries that do all of this work for you, you shouldn't have to do it yourself in a massive loop!

Here is some [**sample code**](http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/displaying-list-of-music-files-stored.html) to help you get started... note that it is a little out-dated in that it makes use of some deprecated methods (such as `managedQuery`, etc.). If you wanted to be entirely 100% correct you would want to make use of the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor` interface introduced in the Honeycomb release, but it's a good start.

To sort the displayed views, you can make use of the `sortOrder` argument in the `ContentProvider`'s `query` method.