# Get all the elements which are starting with a specified string from an Array List

Tags: java, android

I am creating an application which displays a search result which is an Array List, based on the user input.  I need to display this result in an order where results are separated with the starting alphabet index, like all elements starting with alphabet "A" will be under the title A, starting with "B" will be under the tile B and so on...

I am successful with retrieving the first char of each element and comparing it with the alphabets but I feel like a log way.  Can any one please suggest me any direct way so that i can get the elements directly?

Thanks in advance, Tim

Comment: I think its better to use [`AutoCompleteListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) for this.

Comment: I need to display the search results in an order and this search may be a contains search by the user.

Comment: You need to sort names in Alphabetic order that's it right?

Comment: check following api: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AlphabetIndexer.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115920/alphabetindexer-with-custom-adapter

Comment: Yes, in alphabetic order, just like the way contacts are displayed on the Android Phone :)

Comment: Can i display the result list separated by an Index Title?

Comment: you can combine SectionIndexer and AlphaIndexer.

Answer (score 1):

If it is display only requirement have a `ArrayList<Set<Title>>` where `ArrayList.get(0)` will give A and the Set will have all Titles

If you want O(1) access (but don't want to Display list structure) use a MultiMap (Map inside a Map) get('A').get('MY TITLE') will straight away return you the value.

Answer (score 0):

Dont compare all. Just use your search item as an index. Constant finding-time. You will need an indexing-function that converts your search item to a number which is unique. For example:

```
lets find "data" word in your list.

d=4, a=1, t=20:

data----->4 + 1*4 + 20*(1+4) + 1*(20+1+4)  just made up this.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression

`^A*\W$` for getting list of strings starting with A

Comment: Or you can just sort your list and try some logic

Comment: List can be sorted using TreeSet, then make a custom method and retrieve values